# uiview in navigation

Tags: iphone

I am working with a navigation application. I have a homeViewController with two views(accept, service). When I click on a button in serviceView it should go to acceptView. I should have back button in navigation bar which takes me be back to serviceView from acceptView. When I am trying to use [self navigationController pushViewController, it only accepts viewcontroller but not view. Can any one please tell the alternative. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some code, it's hard to know what is wrong without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a different `viewController` for each view if you wish to use a `navigationController` properly.

Set up `AcceptViewController` and `ServiceViewController` separately. Then, from the `AcceptViewController`, you can create a `ServiceViewController` and push it onto the stack as follows:

```
-(void)showServiceView {
ServiceViewController *serviceViewController = [[ServiceViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:serviceViewController];
[serviceViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've references to both `acceptView` and `serviceView`, you can just make this work by removing one as the subview and adding the other one as the subview of `homeViewController`'s `view`. Something like,

```
[serviceView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:acceptView];
```

for moving to `acceptView`. Switch them if you want to come back. However this mechanism will be abrupt. Use `UIView`'s `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` method to animate the transition. Something like,

```
[UIView transitionFromView:serviceView
                    toView:acceptView
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft| UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                completion:NULL];
```

This will remove `serviceView` and add `acceptView` as the subview along with a transition to go by.

Comment: @din Did this help? Do you need any further help with this problem?